# How can I send a array by WiFi/Bluetooth?

Tags: ios, arrays, bluetooth, wifi, multipeer-connectivity

I use the Multipeer Connectivity Framework

sending text correctly but as I can send other data

-Send text:

```
NSData *dataToSend = [_txtMessage.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray *allPeers = _appDelegate.mcManager.session.connectedPeers;
NSError *error;

[_appDelegate.mcManager.session sendData:dataToSend
                                 toPeers:allPeers
                                withMode:MCSessionSendDataReliable
                                   error:&error];

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);    
}

[_txtMessage setText:@""];
[_txtMessage resignFirstResponder];
```

-Receive text:

```
-(void)didReceiveDataWithNotification:(NSNotification *)notification{
    MCPeerID *peerID = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"peerID"];
    NSString *peerDisplayName = peerID.displayName;

    NSData *receivedData = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSString *receivedText = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

}
```

`NSMutableArray *arraySongs;`
But how send and receive array?

sorry for my bad English

Added from comment for formatting and continuity:

```
MPMediaQuery *everything = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];
NSLog(@"Logging items from a generic query...");
NSArray *itemsFromGenericQuery = [everything items];
for (MPMediaItem *song in itemsFromGenericQuery) {
    NSString *songTitle = [song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
    NSString *artist = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
    long totalPlaybackTime = [[song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration] longValue];
    [arraySongs addObject:song];
}
```

type array

```
MPMediaQuery * todo = [[alloc MPMediaQuery] init];
```

NSLog (@ "elementos de registro de una consulta genérica ..."); 
NSArray * itemsFromGenericQuery = [Elementos de muebles]; for (MPMediaItem * canción en itemsFromGenericQuery) 
{NSString * songtitle = [canción valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle]; 
NSString * artista = [canción valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyArtist]; 
largo totalPlaybackTime = [[canción valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration] longValue]; 
[ArraySongs addObject: song]; }

Comment: What kind of objects does the `NSArray` contain?

Comment: MPMediaQuery *everything = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"Logging items from a generic query...");
    NSArray *itemsFromGenericQuery = [everything items];
    for (MPMediaItem *song in itemsFromGenericQuery) {
        NSString *songTitle = [song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
       
        NSString *artist = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
        
        long totalPlaybackTime = [[song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration] longValue];
      
        [arraySongs addObject:song];
    }

Comment: You can edit your question to add more information, code. I added the above comment code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize an `NSArray` to JSON data with `dataWithJSONObject:options:error:`
Send the data
Restore to an `NSArray` with `JSONObjectWithData:options:error:`.

This is assuming that all the components of the `NSArray` are supported by JSON serialization.

For a array that has more complex objects use `NSArchiver` and add support for `NSCoding` to any objects that do not already implement that protocol.

`MPMediaItem` conforms to NSCoding so you can serialize with `NSArchiver` but `JSON`.

Comment: `MPMediaItem` conforms to `NSCoding` so you can serialize with `NSArchiver` but JSON.